# I don't want my card to decrease in size from 400px

Tags: css, card

By the way, I would like my cards in the most popular ones to stop decreasing in size from a resolution of 400px I tried to add a `min-width` on the card container but with all that the result is nothing.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  .aside-container {
    min-width: 400px;
  }
}
```

[I don't want my card to decrease in size from 400px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4M5q4.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are using a media query that will only work when your screen is less than 400px wide.  You might want to remove that, or maybe you meant min-width?

Comment: This is exactly what I want, I want that from a width less than 400px the cards do not decrease in size that's why I added the min-width property to the container but the problem that arises is that it does not work at all at least not correctly

Answer (score 0):

Notice, that actual rule that is applied to your `.aside-container` is `(max-width: 786px)`.

I believe that rule `@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {` is placed before `(max-width: 786px)` rule in your `queries.css`. Try to move code down to end of file so needed rule will be last applied to element.

I have no time to verify it right now but I'll get to computer later so I'll check it.

Comment: Regarding the layout of the media queries I have placed the max-width 400px after that of 765 px the problem arises elsewhere I do not know if I am using the correct css property so that the cards no longer move from a width less than 400px despite the fact that I have added a min-widht to the container